# How to check mimeType against a specific set of mimeTypes?

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

Original code:

```
if($mimeType == 'image/jpeg' or $mimeType == 'image/png' or $mimeType == 'image/gif' && filename)
```

I tried this, but it will include unwanted *.pdf

```
if ($mimeType == ('image/jpeg' ||'image/png' ||'image/gif') && filename)
```

How do I make the code shorter?

And why the inner parentheses are not working?

Comment: You could make an array of accepted mime types and check if the supplied mimetype is in_array..

Comment: i think its short  even though you think its big  ;)

Comment: @JimL, thanks, but it won't make it any shorter.

Comment: You're missing `$` before your variable.

Comment: if(preg_match("/image\/(jpeg|gif|png)/",$mimeType) && $filename)

Comment: @RayCLin Regex can be expensive.  You will find that most of the informed volunteers on SO will advise against using preg functions unless it is essential.  You can do it like that, but it will be slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using || like that will always evaluate to true. You could use an array:

```
if(in_array($mimeType, array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif')) && $part->filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `in_array()`:

```
$allowed_types = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
if (in_array($mime_type, $allowed_types)) {
    ...
}
```